# Heisenberg bug `invalid_grant` in BigQuery?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I use multiple computers, laptops and servers, which I use to run BigQuery on the same account. Now with one computer, I am getting the error for running bigquery script with Python pandas `pd.read_gbq` such that

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_gbq(query='''select  1''', project_id=7777777, dialect='legacy')

invalid_grant: Bad Request', '{\n  "error" : "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description" : "Bad Request
```

which I get with some weeks but not with others so hence calling this Heisenberg bug, not sure whether caused by the issue that I have many computers in usage.

**How can I resolve the BigQuery invalid_grant error? Has python wrong version of `client_secrets.json` (I could not find it locally)?**

Comment: Are you using service accounts? i.e. how are you authenticating..

Comment: @GrahamPolley how can I find it out? I did `gcloud auth login`, ok ok in Anaconda but still getting the error. I added a small example where I get the error with pandas, I have tried uninstalling the pandas multiple times but not helping with the error, where does the pandas read_gbq loads the credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There are multiple ways for the authentication, I provide the solution with service account as hinted in a comment.*

**Service account**

You can create a service account [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials), instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file). Then, use read_gbq with the `private_key` parameter such that

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('BQ.json')
a=pd.read_gbq(query='select 1', project_id='', dialect='standard', private_key='BQ.json')
print(a)
```

where it did not initially work without `from google.cloud import bigquery` but after first successful connection, it started to work without the client as well.